# Proof that the square of a stochastic matrix is stochastic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-matrices

We know that the square of a stochastic matrix is also stochastic, because the two-step transition matrix of a Markov chain is necessarily stochastic. However, in there another way to independently prove this fact?

Comment: Do you know the definition of stochastic matrix?

Comment: All the entries in a row (or column) sum to 1.

Comment: Then the conclusion follows the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do for column-stochastic matrix. Let $X=(x_{ij})$. Then the
sum of the entries of the first column of $X^2$ is $(x_{11}+...+x_{n1})x_{11}+(x_{12}+...+x_{n2})x_{21}+...=x_{11}+...+x_{n1}=1$. Of course, this works for any column.